# Callback when parsing with oj gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

I'd like to understand how to understand the way to apply transformation (underscore in my case) on each key when parsing a JSON file with Oj.

For example in ruby/rails :

```
require 'oj'
Oj.optimize_rails()

def transform_keys(hash)
  hash.deep_transform_keys { |k| k.to_s.underscore }
end

data = '{ "JsonKey": "JsonValue", "JsonKey2": { "JsonSubKey2": "JsonSubValue" }, "Array": ["ValueArray1","ValueArray2"] }'
data2 = '[{ "JsonKey": "JsonValue", "JsonKey2": { "JsonSubKey2": "JsonSubValue" }, "Array": ["ValueArray1","ValueArray2"] }]'

json_data = JSON.parse(data)

case json_data
when Hash
  transform_keys(json_data)
when Array
  json_data.map { |hash| transform_keys(hash) }
end
```

This do the job but it iterate twice : one during parsing and for apply the transformation.

Checking oj, I found :

- ::Oj::ScHandler http://www.ohler.com/oj/doc/Oj/ScHandler.html
- ::Oj::Saj http://www.ohler.com/oj/doc/Oj/Saj.html

Let's try :

```
class UnderscoreKeyHandler < ::Oj::ScHandler
  def hash_start
    {}
  end

  def hash_set(h,k,v)
    h[k.to_s.underscore] = v
  end

  def array_start
    []
  end

  def array_append(a,v)
    a << v
  end

  def add_value(v)
  end
end
handler = UnderscoreKeyHandler.new
Oj.sc_parse(handler, data)
```

It work! Ok, let's benchmark this :

```
require 'oj'
Oj.optimize_rails()
hash = Hash.new
key = 'abcd'
1000.times { hash[key.succ!] = hash.keys }
json = hash.to_json; nil

def transform_keys(hash)
  hash.deep_transform_keys { |k| k.to_s.underscore }
end


10000 * Benchmark.realtime { 
  json_data = JSON.parse(json)
  case json_data
  when Hash
    transform_keys(json_data)
  when Array
    json_data.map { |hash| transform_keys(hash) }
  end
} # Between 2400 and 3500

10000 * Benchmark.realtime { Oj.sc_parse(handler, json) } # Between 700 and 1600
```

Perfect? I seem to be but i feel insecure...

In fact i just want to override each key for a hash and not rewrite a full handler. Is there a way?

Moreover :

- What is the difference between ::Oj::ScHandler and ::Oj::Saj ?
- What are the risk of using a custom handler
- What is the purpose of the add_value method.
- How can i raise another error than the Oj::ParseError default error?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I was at the end of the post. Maybe it was not clear. I just edited.

Comment: “i don't understand/see” is a statement, not a question.